# MySQL Select : where time is greater then and less than time

Tags: mysql, between

I have a function that accepts two time parameters: `$start_time`, `$end_time`
each parameter is define as time in php as

```
$start_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($start)); ->like "06:12:44"
$end_time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($end)); ->like "08:22:14"
```

I want to build a query that gives the results between these times
This is my function

```
function statistics_connected_hour($gateway_id , $date_sql ,$start_time ,$end_time){
$statistics_connected = mysql_query(

    "SELECT * 
       FROM cdr_table 
       WHERE OwnerUserID ='$_SESSION[user_id]'
       AND GatewayID = $gateway_id
       AND DATE(Dialed) = $date_sql
       AND Dialed != 0
       AND Hour(StartTime) BETWEEN ('$start_time') AND ('$end_time')
    "); 

return $statistics_connected;
}
```

StartTime Column in the DB define as "2012-12-28 13:32:28"

The query does not return any results although there are supposed to return 
When I check  ->

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($statistics_connected);
```

It always returns 0 in $num

Can anyone help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: It doesn't work because `HOUR()` returns a single number (the hour), but you're comparing against a time string.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time), not [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour).

```
SELECT * FROM cdr_table 
WHERE OwnerUserID = '$_SESSION[user_id]'
  AND GatewayID = $gateway_id
  AND DATE(Dialed) = $date_sql
  AND Dialed != 0
  AND TIME(StartTime) BETWEEN '$start_time' AND '$end_time'
```

Also, I'd *strongly* suggest escaping all variables you're embedding in SQL code with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) or equivalent, even if you're sure there's nothing harmful in them, just to make it a habit.

Note that a query like this may be intrinsically inefficient, since it cannot make use of indexes on the `StartTime` column.  If there are a lot of potentially matching rows in the table, it could be a good idea to denormalize your table by creating a separate column storing *only* the time part of the `StartTime` and setting up an index on it (possibly combined with other relevant columns).

Comment: The StartTime Column in the DB define as  "2012-12-28 13:32:28"

Comment: I found the problem: the change from Hour to Time helped but the value of the given parameters was wrong time  so i change it and the problem is solved thanks

Comment: I cannot change the database it comes from a very complicated system and i can only read data from it but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are extracting the HOUR and comparing with the time, you need to cast the time part
Try your query as::

```
SELECT 

* 
FROM cdr_table 
WHERE 
OwnerUserID ='$_SESSION[user_id]' 
AND GatewayID = $gateway_id 
AND DATE(Dialed) = $date_sql 
AND Dialed != 0 
AND DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%r') BETWEEN ('$start_time') AND ('$end_time')
```

Comment: This is what I tried but it still does not work
You can see the function above