# Get data from between time by mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to get data from less than 2 hours of current time and greater than 2 hours of current time.In DB table i have created 2 fields one is start time and other is close time.both fields are in VARCHAR format.Below my database table.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B3kf.png

I have created mysql query but this is not working.

```
select * 
  from table_name 
 where TIME_FORMAT('states','h:i %A') > '$curr-2 ' 
   and TIME_FORMAT('close_time','h:i %A') < '$curr+2'

$curr-2 = Current time - 2 Hours (minus) 
$curr+2 = Current time + 2 Hours (Plus)
```

This sql is not working.

Comment: you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085923/mysql-select-where-time-is-greater-then-and-less-than-time

Comment: You should consider in change that fields type to a more precise data like timestamp for instance.

Comment: Don't use "varchar" to store datetime fields, if you can at all avoid it!!!!  And if you must, be sure to use W3C or (better) ISO 8601 format strings.

Answer (score 1):

if the fields were `datetime` or `time` it would make more sense surely? However, the following might do what you are after...

```
select * from `table_name`
   where 
   time_format( time( now() ),'%h:%i') 
   between 
     time( concat( time_format( `states`,'%h')+2,':',time_format( `states`,'%i') ) ) 
   and 
     time( concat( time_format( `close_time`,'%h')+2,':',time_format( `close_time`,'%i') ) )
```

Comment: we need to less then 2 hours from states and more then 2 hours from close time

Answer (score 1):

You really should change those fields to a DATETIME to make this easier, however the below query will work and i've provided an SQL fiddle.

*Please Note I set the hours to 12 instead of 2 on the fiddle to ensure it shows a working query*

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/579db/37/0

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` 
WHERE 
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1971-01-01 ', `states`), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') > DATE_SUB(CONCAT('1971-01-01 ', CURRENT_TIME()), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
AND 
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1971-01-01 ', `close_time`), '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') < DATE_ADD(CONCAT('1971-01-01 ', CURRENT_TIME()), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```